# Overriding an edit rejection?

Tags: discussion, edits

An old answer of mine was attempted to be edited (not by me) but the edit was rejected (not by me). I think the editor's change suggestion has merit though I'm not invested enough to be certain. I've edited my answer to include the rejected content and attribute it, along with my brief thoughts, but it bothers me that this takes credit away from the person that identified the change and suggested it. In general, what should my actions be to ensure that the proper editor receives credit in a case such as this?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8859978

Comment: Touching code in an edit is ALWAYS iffy. I think you did the right thing by including this, YOURSELF, in your answer.

Comment: The editor should have probably suggested the change in the comments, You could then edit the answer and credit him properly, and his contribution would be right there for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, fixing code in a post changes the nature of the post.

For example, in questions, I've seen "minor" corrections that actually *answered the OP's question* (in which case the edit should have been an answer). Modifications to code should generally not be done, and especially not by [sub-2k editors](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (who have less experience with the site and thus have less understanding of when it's appropriate).

In addition, reviewers do not necessarily have and do not necessarily need expertise in a particular subject matter to make a judgment call about a particular edit. Such a requirement would make reviews of some tags almost impossible to complete. If a reader notices a minor code issue and doesn't have the 2k rep needed to fix it, then a comment would always be the appropriate action (as [others had done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651804/android-sqlite-checking-if-tables-contain-rows/7651817#comment46528510_7651817) for this post). Code edits will often be rejected by reviewers.

Your approach was fair and I applaud you for taking the time to make your post clearer, but the system is working exactly as it should.